# Jenkins pipeline to publish war generated in Node + Gulp project to Artifactory

Tags: jenkins, npm, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I have a `gulp build` which creates a `war` file in `build` directory.

Is there a Jenkins pipeline to publish this `war` file directly to Artifactory.

Note that I am using a declarative pipeline for Jenkins

Answer (score 0):

The [JFrog Artifactory plugin](https://github.com/JFrog/jenkins-artifactory-plugin) for Jenkins has support for [declarative pipelines](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Declarative+Pipeline+Syntax).
You can use the rtUpload command for uploading files to Artyifactory

```
rtUpload (
    serverId: 'Artifactory-1',
    spec: '''{
          "files": [
            {
              "pattern": "build/war/*.war",
              "target": "my-repo/my-path/"
            }
         ]
    }''',

    // Optional - Associate the uploaded files with the following custom build name and build number,
    // as build artifacts.
    // If not set, the files will be associated with the default build name and build number (i.e the
    // the Jenkins job name and number).
    buildName: 'my-build',
    buildNumber: '42'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also required a buildNumber requirement, but I want to update it externally, so whenever I have a Jenkins job run,, the buildNumber updates automatically in the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH (eg. 1.0.0) format.